# Backpressuring on async Flow in Akka Streams

Tags: multithreading, scala, akka-stream

I have this flow component in Akka streams

```
object ExecutionFlow {
    def apply(
         execute: In => Future[Out],
         parallelism: Int)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Flow[In, Out, NotUsed] =
      Flow[In]
        .async // make the streams run asynchronously. essential for throughput
        .mapAsyncUnordered(parallelism){
          case (in) => execute(in)
        }
}
```

Here In and Out are two data types and execute is a heavy weight expensive operation. There is a thread pool executor on which these operations run. Its set up like this

```
private val threadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(10, 10, 300, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue[Runnable]())
```

Here corepool size is 10, maxPool size is 10, 300 is the ttl in seconds. Note that this is akka explicitly handing over execution to another thread pool.

Now when I use this flow, as soon as messages come into the Execution flow its delegated to this thread pool executor and and a new one comes in, the flow lets messages in and the threadpool suddenly spikes up in its active thread count. I lowered the parallelism value down to 1 and removed .async too but the problem is still present.

When I do this however

```
object ExecutionFlow {
    def apply(
         execute: In => Future[Out], timeout: FiniteDuration): Flow[In, Out, NotUsed] =
      Flow[In]
        .map){ case (in) => Await.result(execute(in), timeout) }
}
```

This problem goes away. I presume the nature of the blocking somehow implicitly slows down the processing here.

I wanted to know what would be a good strategy to effectively back pressure here so that I do not have to deal with active thread usage spikes.

I am looking at https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/index.html#backpressure-aware-operators to see if I can come up with some scheme but I am at a loss.

Comment: Have you tried parallelism = 1 and no `.async`?  Since you're not using the `implicit ec`, you should probably also take that out.

Comment: Yea I did. It did not help.

Comment: What do you mean by "the threadpool suddenly spikes up in its active thread count"?

Comment: We have a bit of telemetry that records threadPoolExecutor.getActiveCount and that number jumps up when traffic into this stream spikes up. This is not a behavior we observe with the Await version.

Comment: By spikes up, you mean goes to 10?

Comment: Yea. So lets say the steady state is 10 threads for 50 requests a second. If the request count jumps up to 300, then that thread count spikes up to 300 for a min and then goes back down to 60. I really cant explain why this is happening only in the async version.

Comment: thread count in that threadpool or across all threadpools? (note that `getActiveCount` is not guaranteed to return an accurate number, especially under load)

Comment: Thread count in that thread pool. The telemetry code is exactly the same in either version of the Flow.

Comment: The 300 is not an accurate number (or you've uncovered a bug in your JVM, but that's somewhat less likely).

Comment: The version with `Await` doesn't put any load on the thread pool because while you're waiting, the upstream and downstream parts of the stream aren't running either.

Comment: Let me put this in another way. Instead of thread usage going up linearly, there is an initial spike of threads before stabilizing back down to its linear relationship every time traffic ramps up. And I have no idea why that's happening.

Comment: Nitpick: The `.async` is redundant with your `.mapAsyncUnordered` which already inserts an asynchronous boundary. The key thing to note is that by default all stages in your graph are fused, in that a single actor processes all stages. `async` basically demarcates the stage up until that point making all downstream messages flow into a different actor's mailbox.

Comment: Why do you reckon your stream isn't backpressured currently though?  Downstream should signal demand only up until parallelism is exhausted . Another thing to note is that when dealing with 3rd party async APIs, the real execution may happen on a dedicated thread pool itself, not necessarily using the execution ctx of your graph. Within the closure of your `mapAsync`, your dedicated thread pool is tasked with _waiting_ for the future(assuming the 3P API is delegating to it's own thread pool). In which case it's natural you'd see higher active threads.

Comment: Yea the 3P API is delegating to its own thread pool @farthVader. It might very well be that that thread pool itself needs to be fine tuned to not scale up and down its thread count very quickly. The problem here is that its consuming unnecessary stack space as these threads are being created and destroyed and this is simply a non problem in the blocking version.

Comment: I put in some more telemetry. It seems these spikes are on threads in timed_waiting state and not in runnable or new state. And then those threads are dissapearing once the load stabilizes to a higher value for a while. This really seems to suggest that the thread pool executor needs some work.